# How to access the second if statement

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

I am totally drain out as the second **`if`** statement couldn't be executed.

My original idea was when volatility is in a range of 90 - 110, the program will send **one and only one** order. And it will wait and see till the volatility reaches in a range of 111 - 150, and then it will send **the second order**.

If I don't use a **`bool`** function here, the program will send **countless** order when the range is reached.

Could someone please help me?

```
  if (  TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage >= 90.0
     && ( dayTrend  == 1 )
     && orderOpened == false
        )
  {
        Print( "Entered if clause" );
     // Print( "Today volatility percentage is: ", TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage + "%" );
     // ticket: Returns number of the ticket assigned to the order by the trade server or -1 if it fails.
        ticket = OrderSend( Symbol(),
                            OP_SELL,
                            0.3,
                            Bid,
                            3,
                             0 * MyPoint,
                            30 * MyPoint,
                            NULL,
                            MagicNumber,
                            0,
                            Blue
                            );
        Print( "Order is opened on", OrderOpenTime()+" at price: ", OrderOpenPrice() );
        Print( "trend number is ",dayTrend );

        if (  ticket > 0 )
        {
              if (  TakeProfit > 0 ) TheTakeProfit = Bid - TakeProfit * MyPoint;
              OrderSelect( ticket, SELECT_BY_TICKET ); // bool value
           /* OrderModify( OrderTicket(),
                           OrderOpenPrice(),
                           0,
                           NormalizeDouble( TheTakeProfit, Digits  ),
                           0,
                           Green
                           );
                         */
        }
        orderOpened = true;
        if (  TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage >= 110.0 ) orderOpened = false;              
  }
  if (  TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage >= 110.0
     && ( dayTrend  == 1 )
     && orderOpened == false
        )
  {
        Print( "Entered second if clause" );
     // ticket: Returns number of the ticket assigned to the order by the trade server or -1 if it fails.
        ticket = OrderSend(  Symbol(),
                             OP_SELL,
                             0.3,
                             Bid,
                             3,
                              0 * MyPoint,
                             30 * MyPoint,
                             NULL,
                             MagicNumber,
                             0,
                             Blue
                             );
        if (  ticket > 0 )
        {
              if (  TakeProfit > 0 ) TheTakeProfit = Bid - TakeProfit * MyPoint;
              OrderSelect( ticket, SELECT_BY_TICKET ); // bool value
           /* OrderModify( OrderTicket(),
                           OrderOpenPrice(),
                           0,
                           NormalizeDouble( TheTakeProfit, Digits ),
                           0,
                           Green
                           );
                       */
        }
        orderOpened = true;
     }
```

Comment: If TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage >= 110.0, then it is for sure, TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage is > 90.0. So put the second if clause in the front, so that logic will be executed. I guess it helps. OR, you might define range for TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage, so you add a check: `if (TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage >=90 && TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage <110)`

Comment: Inside your first `if(TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage>=90.0` body, you also have `if(TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage>=110.0)`, but nothing writes to `TodayMaxVolatilityPercentage` (in the code you've shown) in-between. Can it really change?

Answer (score 0):

### A hidden show-stopper:

By design, the first successful **`OrderSend()`** returns a value you assign into an **`ticket = OrderSend(...)`**.

The devil is hidden in detail.

`[MQL4-Help]` says:

> Returns **number** of the ticket assigned to the order by the trade server or **`-1`** if it fails.

So the first successful `OrderSend()` ticket# returned is `0` ( in StrategyTester, a real MT4/Server rather runs into high numbers drawn from it's `db.pool` of tickets ).

Thus the second **`if ( ticket > 0 )`** will never let you in.

It is common to rather use **`if ( ticket > EMPTY )`** so as to also clarify the intention and use symbolic instead of a `-1` integer constant.